# Getting scrollTop() to perform only once

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want scrollTop to trigger only once, so that the red box doesn't appear again after it has been closed with the button.

I know there is .one(), but I have no idea how to apply it to my code. Below is my code and jsfiddle.

```
<div id="box-pop">This is a red box.
    <button class="box-close">Close</button>
</div>


$(document).scroll(function () {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
        $('#box-pop').fadeIn(500);
    }
});
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".box-close").click(function () {
        $("#box-pop").fadeOut(200)
    });

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3LG6t/3/

Answer (score 3):

For a better performance in your page, what about this?

```
$("#box-pop").fadeOut(200,function(){
    $(this).remove();
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/3LG6t/5/

And take a look at this topics:

1. [Differences between detach(), hide() and remove() - jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4942070/differences-between-detach-hide-and-remove-jquery)
2. [jQuery detach() v/s remove() v/s hide()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12210381/jquery-detach-v-s-remove-v-s-hide)
3. [Why remove() or detach() instead of hide()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22438257/why-remove-or-detach-instead-of-hide)

Answer (score 2):

One is used the same way bind or on is.  Scroll itself really isn't an actual function but a shortcut to on that performs the following:

```
.on('scroll', function () {

}
```

However you need to get something to work once after a condition, so you would use off after using on.

```
<div id="box-pop">This is a red box.
    <button class="box-close">Close</button>
</div>


$(document).on('scroll', function fadeBoxIn() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
        $('#box-pop').fadeIn(500);
        $(document).off('scroll', fadeBoxIn);

    }
});
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".box-close").click(function () {
        $("#box-pop").fadeOut(200)
    });

});
```

See the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/V6QWV/3/).

Comment: Change it to `$(this).off('scroll');` and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Try `$( "document").unbind( "scroll" );` :

```
$(document).scroll(function () {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
    $('#box-pop').fadeIn(500);
  }
});
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".box-close").click(function () {
    $("#box-pop").fadeOut(200)
    $(document).unbind("scroll");        
  });
});
```

or conditionally rebind the scroll function within the `$(".box-close").click()`.

Comment: I would suggest unbinding the event handler right after the box is shown.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using scroll for other functionallity, you need to create separate function, otherwise see @Gavin42 example

```
fadeInBox = function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 100) {
        $('#box-pop').fadeIn(500);
    }
}

$(document).on('scroll', fadeInBox);
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".box-close").click(function () {
        $(document).off('scroll', fadeInBox);
        $("#box-pop").fadeOut(200);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the mention. With web pages, and specifically with `jQuery`, it's hard to ever know if unbinding something will wreak havoc on the rest of the page unless you can see all of the code.