# Does using jquery.detach() improve performance?

Tags: jquery

Does using `jquery.detach()` and doing operations on the detached node and the appending it improve performance?

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12210381/jquery-detach-v-s-remove-v-s-hide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It causes a memory leak if you don't put the element(s) back in the document somewhere. jQuery will keep all the data (as in `element.data()` and references to event handlers) in memory when you use `.detach`.

That is the purpose of `.detach`: to *not* clean up because you are promising to put the elements back into the page soon. If you were not going to put them back, you would use `.remove` and that would clean up the data.

It is not about performance.